# Extending projection DAC in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I can not extend properly projection DAC in Acumatica.

It did not write data to database or Read data.

Any thoughts about that?

Comment: Please explain with your code. Otherwise we don't know what you have done there.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

need to set on field code like: BqlField = typeof(INRegisterExt.usrSOrderNbr)

to link to real bql field